# Refreshing an UpdatePanel inside of a modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

Obviously I am doing something wrong, just not sure what...
I have a modal popup and inside of that is an Update Panel which in turn contains a gridview. When the modal popup is first called I would like to refresh the UpdatePanel (and grid data).

I have the code working so that the panel is updated when a button is pressed btnHiddenJSRefresh (currently not hidden). But I can not get this to work without having to press the button!

I've tried 'clicking' the button via Jquery $("<%= btnHiddenJSRefresh.ClientID %>").click();
And I can see it gets called, but there is no reaction on the page. 
Same with __doPostBack("<%= btnHiddenJSRefresh.ClientID %>", "");

Also (and this may be unrelated) the delete option in the gridview does not work here. Outside of the UpdatePanel it works fine...

Here's the code, I've tried to reduce it down to the main area of issue

```
<ajaxact:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
cancelcontrolid="ClosePopup" okcontrolid="ClosePopup"
targetcontrolid="hidenSelectedDoc" popupcontrolid="THolder"
popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" BehaviorID="MPE" Y="0" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">
```

```
<div classs="ModalPopup" id="THolder" >
    <a id="ClosePopup" href="#">Close</a>
    <asp:Button ID="btnHiddenJSRefresh" runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="btnAddTag_Click" />

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="UpdatePanel2_Load" >

        <ContentTemplate>            
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPageTags" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePageTags"  CssClass="TableDataHolder" DataKeyNames="CarID" >
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" SortExpression="FullName" />                               
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                                <ItemTemplate>                                           
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteButtonImg" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this car?');" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/DeleteIconS.png" AlternateText="Delete" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>                             
                    </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePageTags" runat="server"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bobConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE (cMake = @cMake)"
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE * FROM Cars WHERE CarID = @CarID">                       
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="cMake" DefaultValue="0" Type="int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>
```

Code behind

```
protected void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSourcePageTags.SelectParameters["cMake"].DefaultValue = hidenSelectedcMake.Value;
        SqlDataSourcePageTags.DataBind();
        gvPageTags.DataBind();
        UpdatePanel2.Update();
    }
```

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to have all the page code that is referenced in your code fragment. In the meantime, I tried to simulate this functionality from your description, so please correct me if I misunderstood something.

On the page load, I added a javascript block to check if it is a postback. If it is not, then I call the button's (btnHiddenJSRefresh) click event once to refesh the modal. Also, I added a button to popup the modal window, see my code example. And finally, the delete option is working fine in this example.

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release">
                <Scripts>
                    <asp:ScriptReference Path="resources/jquery-1.11.0.js"/>
                </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
         var chkPostBack = '<%= Page.IsPostBack ? "true" : "false" %>';             

         if ( !Boolean.parse(chkPostBack) ) {                
             __doPostBack("<%= btnHiddenJSRefresh.ClientID %>", "");
         }
     });
</script>  


<asp:Button ID="shwmodal" runat="server" Text="show modal" 
    onclick="shwmodal_Click" />

<div classs="ModalPopup" id="THolder" >


<a id="ClosePopup" href="#">Close</a>



<asp:Button ID="btnHiddenJSRefresh" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none" OnClick="btnAddTag_Click" />



<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional" 
OnLoad="UpdatePanel2_Load" >

    <ContentTemplate>            
<asp:GridView ID="gvPageTags" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourcePageTags"  CssClass="TableDataHolder" DataKeyNames="RoleID" >
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Descr" HeaderText="Descr Name" SortExpression="Descr" />                               
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                            <ItemTemplate>                                           
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="deleteButtonImg" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this car?');" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/DeleteIconS.png" AlternateText="Delete" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>                             
                </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourcePageTags" runat="server"
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:bobConnectionString %>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM testRoles WHERE (RoleId = @cMake)"
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM testRoles WHERE RoleId = @RoleId">

                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="cMake" DefaultValue="0" Type="int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

</div>           


 <cc1:ModalPopupExtender id="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
    cancelcontrolid="ClosePopup" okcontrolid="ClosePopup"
    targetcontrolid="hidenSelectedDoc" popupcontrolid="THolder"
    popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="true" BehaviorID="MPE" Y="0" backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG">       
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
     <asp:Button runat="server" 
        ID="hidenSelectedDoc" 
        style="display:none"/> 



</form>
```